# Is a quark‘s constituent mass affected by the chiral limit?

Tags: mass, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

The up- and down quark’s constituent mass is usually taken to be around $300\,\text{MeV}\approx \tfrac{1}{3} m_\text{proton}$. Is this quantity affected by the chiral limit, where we let the quarks’ running mass go to zero?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no, but essentially no.

The constituent masses for the *d* and *u*, respectively, are
336 and 340MeV.

Their respective current masses are 4.3-5.2MeV and 1.8-2.8MeV.

So the current masses are negligible w.r.t. the constituent ones, of the order of 1%. Moreover, as you see, the current *u* is lighter than the *d*, but after chiral symmetry breaking the *u* is ever so slightly heavier than the *d*. There is a lot of slop in these determinations, and also electromagnetic effects, etc.

The takeaway expectation, then, is that setting the current masses equal to 0 would not take you far away from 330MeV.

Comment: Does this mean that a quark‘s current mass and the dynamically generated mass are completely unrelated?

Comment: They are weakly related, in a non-obvious way.

Comment: I see. Do you know where I could do some further reading? I tried searching on the arXiv, but apparently I haven’t found the right papers yet.

Comment: Perhaps the lattice gauge articles pinning down the current masses......

Comment: Are you referring to quark condensation by ud mass after chiral symmetry breaking?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, precisely.